# PHP CSV import script 'Undefined offset' errors

Tags: php, csv, pdo

I'm building the following script and trying to insert each row using PDO.

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Andy
 * Date: 13/03/2016
 * Time: 18:15
 */
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

//connect to the database
require_once('./members/config/database.php');

if (isset($_FILES['uploadedfile'])) {

    // get the csv file and open it up
    $file = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'];
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    try {
        // prepare for insertion
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('
            INSERT INTO memberstest (
                user_healer_number,
                user_real_name,
                user_email,
                user_address,
                user_phone,
                user_mobile_number,
                user_paid_until,
                user_name,
                user_password_hash
            ) VALUES (
                :memberNumber,
                :memberRealName,
                :memberEmail,
                :memberAddress,
                :memberHomePhone,
                :memberMobilePhone,
                :memberPaidUntil,
                :memberUserName,
                :memberPassword
            )
        ');

        $stmt->bindParam(':memberNumber', $data[0]);
        $stmt->bindParam(':memberRealName', $data[1].' '.$data[2]);
        $stmt->bindParam(':memberEmail', $data[11]);
        $stmt->bindParam(':memberAddress', $data[3].' '.$data[4].' '.$data[5].' '.$data[6].' '.$data[7].' '.$data[8]);
        $stmt->bindParam(':memberHomePhone', $data[9]);
        $stmt->bindParam(':memberMobilePhone', $data[10]);
        $stmt->bindParam(':memberPaidUntil', $data[12]);
        $stmt->bindParam(':memberUserName', $data[0]);
        $stmt->bindParam(':memberPassword', strtolower($user_password_hash));

        // unset the first line like this
        fgets($handle);

        // created loop here
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== FALSE) {
            $stmt->execute($data);
        }

        fclose($handle);

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

    echo 'Projects imported';

} else {
    echo 'Could not import projects';
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Import a CSV File with PHP & MySQL</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php if (!empty($_GET['success'])) { echo "<b>Your file has been imported.</b><br><br>"; } //generic success notice ?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
    Choose your file: <br />
    <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" id="csv" />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

But I keep getting the following errors:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/spha/csv-import-2.php on line 47
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/spha/csv-import-2.php on line 47
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/spha/csv-import-2.php:47 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/spha/csv-import-2.php on line 47

Line 47 is `$stmt->bindParam(':memberRealName', $data[1].' '.$data[2]);`

and an example of the CSV is this:

```
H3,Wilfred,Baker,Woodcott,none,Hardington Moor,town,county,postcode,01935 123456,None,email@domain.com,31/03/2016
```

I've looked at a few questions/answers on here but don't 100% understand where I'm going wrong.

Any help is appreciated

Andy

Comment: I guess you cannot have this `$data[1].' '.$data[2]` in bind param

Comment: `$data[1]` and `$data[2]` don't exist. Also you can't pass a concatenated string to `bind`, you have to pass a variable.

Comment: try define variable for : $data[1].' '.$data[2] like : $foo = $data[1].' '.$data[2]; and use $foo in your bind

Comment: Hmmm okay, let me test some stuff

Comment: Okay so that appears to fix those errors, but i get undefined variable $data?

Comment: you have to declare it before using it.

Comment: Let me just look through these comments and see if i can work anything out. Still nothing so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to change to :

```
$stmt->bindParam(':memberRealName', $data[1].' '.$data[2]);
```

This:

```
$merged_value = $data[1].' '.$data[2];

$stmt->bindParam(':memberRealName', $merged_value);
```

To hide php notice add the below code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

Comment: I still get errors, i've put all concatenated values into variables and it's saying undefined variable data :/

Comment: you can add this `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);` to hide notices

Comment: Hiding the notice won't fix that this code isn't inserting to the database :P

Comment: I cant see from where you are getting data in your `data[0], data[1]` etc

Comment: you are opening your file in read mode and then directly inserting into database. Where are you looping through the file contents?

Comment: `while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== FALSE) {
            $stmt->execute($data);
        }`

Comment: @AndyHolmes ok so your insert has to go inside while because that's where you are fetching all the data frm file

Comment: `$data` inside while will fetch you file data. Why are you executing it there? Please go through this link on how to read file: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: Okay so I've done what others suggested and concatenated my strings into variables and then passed those into the binds, and now I get `SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`

Comment: I'm sorry I don't follow. I have this: `$stmt->bindParam(':memberRealName', $data[1].' '.$data[2]);` which you said i need to put into a merged variable, which I have done. I've done the same for the address and i get the error above

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a chat? This conversation is not helpful for a community.

Comment: @AndyHolmes have you merged all the variables?

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala all i had to do was remove $data from inside the execute statement.

Comment: @AndyHolmes glad you got it!